# Redirect parameter `state` is missing in case of error

Tags: bug, login, api, authentication, oauth

Testing OAuth authorization in my app I noticed a case when `state` parameter is not passed to redirect uri. I use `state` to track auth process at server side.
If user doesn't authorize application, he is bounced to `redirect_uri` only with parameters `error` and `error_description`.

Here is a line from my access.log:

```
134.236.11.119 - - [29/Mar/2018:14:23:06 +0700] "GET /oauth-callback?error=access_denied&error_description=user%20did%20not%20authorize%20application HTTP/1.1" 303 178 "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=12127&accountId=4375733&scope=no_expiry&returnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2foauth%3fresponse_type%3dcode%26client_id%3d12127%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253A%252F%252F*****.tk%252Foauth-callback%26scope%3dno_expiry%26state%3d8vi2lPZoODYudYeUuXcLffoc1cIMdN&nonce=Pyo*SZtzL4U3ppk9qjVoxA))&ticks=636579049821787524&flowKind=Explicit&hash=2beaa0e4e16b5c12859c2cb853ab90a8216998f7b17928e87fbba6532e1b65eb" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Confirmed. And seems to be against RFC 6749 requirements (at first glance).